# Using JSON.stringify on [object Object] gives "[object Object]" on React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, object

I am trying to pass an object data from one page to another.
I have a line of code that can pass id and I tried to use it to pass object rather than an integer id but I can't get it right.

**The code for passing id from source page:**

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
id && navigate(generatePath("/employeelistedit/:id", { id })); //sample code which works fine when used
```

**The code for passing the object data from source page copying the format of the code above:**

```
function sourcePage(){
 const navigate = useNavigate();
 var values = {id: "someData", startd: "someData", endd: "someData"}
 values && navigate(generatePath("/harvestcalendarmonitoring/:values", { values }));
    } //with useNavigate and generatePath
```

**This is the code in another page which receives the data:**

```
const { values } = useParams(); //values gives [object Object]
 const x = JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(values)) //gives "[object Object]"
 const y = Object.prototype.toString.call(values) //gives [object String]
```

**For my routing, this is how I wrote it:**

```
<Route path="/harvestcalendarmonitoring/:values" element={< Harvestcalendarmonitoring />} /> //refers to the receiving page
```

I know I'm not doing it right cause I know that "[object Object]" is showing that something is wrong somewhere in my codes.
Any help and suggestions would be really much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Steve through his comment above/below this comment,
use JSON.stringify() for the object before passing and receive it using JSON.parse().

**Code in source page:**

```
values = JSON.stringify(values);
values && navigate(generatePath("/harvestcalendarmonitoring/:values", { values }));
```

**Code in receiving page:**

```
const {values} = useParams();
const w = JSON.parse(values) //the w variable gives the desired and/or expected object data
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you missed the stringify step:

```
function sourcePage(){
 const navigate = useNavigate();
 var values = JSON.stringify({id: "someData", startd: "someData", endd: "someData"});
 values && navigate(generatePath("/harvestcalendarmonitoring/:values", { values }));
    } //with useNavigate and generatePath
```

However, make sure `generatePath` is also URL encoding this string `values` or else you will likely have an invalid URL.

When it comes time to parsing the string back into an object, be sure to call `JSON.parse`

Comment: the stringify works and i need to receive it with JSON.parse() in the receiving page. thank you!